# I had already installed and activated my virtual environment but now its not working yet files are there

Tags: python, visual-studio, virtualenv, tweepy

I had already installed and activated my virtual environment in visual studio. Everything was working fine but now, all the imported packages are saying they don't exist. This means my virtual is not activated. I try activating it but still it shows me the installed packages are not existing yet I can see them.

This is the error

```
Kweronda@DESKTOP-MT2OV1I MINGW64 ~/Desktop/tweetbot/src (master)
$ python tweek.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tweek.py", line 7, in <module>    
    import bs4
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'bs4'

Kweronda@DESKTOP-MT2OV1I MINGW64 ~/Desktop/tweetbot/src (master)
$
```

I have bs4 and other packages imported as well as you see here below

```
import random
import re
from turtle import delay
import dotenv
import requests
import bs4

#creating a quotes file
import json as _json

#creating tweet
import os
import time
import tweepy
```

Allow me attach the file structure of my project here
[image: file structure of my project. the imported packaes are there but running the project says they are not imported]

Comment: what happens when you try to reactivate your virtual env? do you get confirmation, or?

Comment: I get nothing. So as you see my file structure, I cd to venv>Script>activate but nothing happens

Comment: Kweronda@DESKTOP-MT2OV1I MINGW64 ~/Desktop/tweetbot/src (master)
$ cd ..

Kweronda@DESKTOP-MT2OV1I MINGW64 ~/Desktop/tweetbot (master)
$ cd venv

Kweronda@DESKTOP-MT2OV1I MINGW64 ~/Desktop/tweetbot/venv (master)
$ cd Scripts

Kweronda@DESKTOP-MT2OV1I MINGW64 ~/Desktop/tweetbot/venv/Scripts (master)
$ activate

Kweronda@DESKTOP-MT2OV1I MINGW64 ~/Desktop/tweetbot/venv/Scripts (master)
$

Comment: Thats the flow but nothin happens

Answer (score 1):

Does your `sys.prefix == sys.base_prefix`? If that's a True, then you aren't in a virtual env. I would check the shell script for the venv activate.

Comment: I'm sorry to ask, but how do I check for that?

Answer (score 1):

I was supposed to activate the activate.bat file, but I was activating just the activate file.
Thanks, everyone for your help.